# vagrant Multipe networking

Tags: networking, docker, vagrant, port, vagrantfile

I have installed magento 2 in vagrant with in docker machine, this docker machine have port forwarding concepts, I set private network, with **nat** and **host-only**, Now only access magento 2 in hostmachine.

I need to access **locally connected remote machine** also so, i try to change private network to public network with bridge.

Vagrant File:

```
     Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

      config.vm.box = "machine"

      config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
      config.vm.hostname = "www.myhost.net"
      config.ssh.forward_agent = "true"


      config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.56.40"

      config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
      end

      if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
        config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"]
      else
        config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"] }

      end

    end
```

But, throw

```
  NFS requires a host-only network to be created.
  Please add a host-only network to the machine (with either DHCP or a
  static IP) for NFS to work.
```

I need to add Multiple Network to vagrant

1. nat
2. host-onloy(for nfs)
3. bridge (for access remote machine)

Suggest me How to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `public_network` to `private_network` for `nfs` to [work](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html)

> If you are using the VirtualBox provider, you will also need to make sure you have a private network set up. This is due to a limitation of VirtualBox's built-in networking. With VMware, you do not need this.

so :

1. you can change to VMWare (but you have some additional fees)
2. you do not use nfs
3. you can setup another network interface for bridge and use this network interface if you need to connect to the remote machine, you should be able to ping (`ping -I ethX mylocalmachine`) but I am not sure how to work to get connection in